# Retrieve file names from inside ZipFile

Tags: c#, zip, ionic-zip

Like the title says, I need to read the names of files from a zip file. I'm going to feed the names into a 2D string array (along with other data). Here's a beginning example of what I'd like to do.

```
private String[,] ArrayFiller(ZipFile MyZip)
{
    int count = 0;
    ZipFile zipfile = ZipFile.Read();
    int zipSize = MyZip.Count;
    string[,] MyArr = new string[zipSize, zipSize];

    foreach (ZipEntry e in zipfile.EntriesSorted)
    {
        //otherArr[count,count] = e; -adds the file, but I need title
    }
    return MyArr;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to find a "file name" property within the ZipFile class. The imported package is called Ionic.Zip.

Maybe it's a property of some kind of zipped object?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the wrong documentation then.

Comment: @hvd Whoops. I'll update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `ZipArchive` Class. From [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples):

```
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.FullName);
            //entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(destFolder, entry.FullName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it looks like you're converting the ZipFile object to a ZipArchive? Keep what I have then and just covert it to a ZipArchive and use the .FullName method on the file "entry"?

Answer (score 3):

You might have more luck with the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) class.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
     {
          // The file name is entry.FullName
     }
}
```